# Cannot use User in Django Rest Framework Custom Request middleware using JWT token after created new middleware

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-middleware

I want to use `request.user` in Django Rest Framework custom middleware.
It returns AnnonymousUser and I failed.

I created new Custom middleware which returns real user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import get_user
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication

class AuthenticationMiddlewareJWT(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: self.__class__.get_jwt_user(request))
        return self.get_response(request)

    @staticmethod
    def get_jwt_user(request):
        user = get_user(request)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return user
        jwt_authentication = JSONWebTokenAuthentication()
        if jwt_authentication.get_jwt_value(request):
            user, jwt = jwt_authentication.authenticate(request)
        return user
```

Above middleware, `jwt_authentication.get_jwt_value(request)`, this returns always None.

How can I fix it and use `request.user` in custom middleware?